# Replacing existing file with assets

Tags: assets

according to the Pixel & Tonic site Assets is capable of doing an replacement of existing files based on filename.  It should allow to upload a new version with the same name (providing me with a choice of replacement) and without breaking existing entries' file links.

However that does not seem to work on my install (EE 2.5.5 and Assets 2.1.2 - coming from 2.0.5 and hoping that upgrading would solve my problem), Assets just creates a new file with a and '-1' suffix in the filename

Any thoughts?
rg,
Tim

Comment: Tim, have you indexed your directories in Assets?

Comment: Yes, I've just did it again.  But still the same issue.  The upgrade to 2.1.2 seem to have brought me a new issue too... now when uploading the same filename I get "Could not upload the file - server returned an unexpected response. Please check the server settings" -- the file gets uploaded anyway afterwards

Comment: Can you go ahead and email super admin details to support@pixelandtonic.com, so I can see this directly to help you out? Thank you!

Comment: it's in your mailbox! rg, Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a follow up for people dealing with the same issue.  Pixel & Tonic have confirmed this issue and it will be resolved in the next release 2.1.3

This update will normally will be released in the week of the 13th of May

rg,

Tim

Comment: 2.1.3 has been released.  I've upgraded and all is well now!